# angular2 wait until observable finishes in if condition

Tags: angular, observable

I have implemented a if statement like this

```ts
if (this.service.check() ) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
}
```

this if condition waits for a response from the backend. But before the observable gets executed it's going into the else statement and finishing the condition without checking the if condition at start.

this is my observable method to get the data from backend

```ts
public check(){
      this.getActorRole().subscribe(
        (resp => {
          if (resp == true){
             return true
         }

        }),
        (error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      );
    }
}
```

So how make the condition waits until it gets the response from the backend

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't wait for an `Observable` or `Promise` to complete. You can only subscribe to it to get notified when it completes or emits an event.

```ts
public check(){
   return this.getActorRole() // <<<=== add return
   .map(resp => {
          if (resp == true){
             return true
         }
      );
    }
}
```

then you can do

```ts
this.service.check().subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
  }
}
```

but if the caller of this code also depends on the return value you again need to

```ts
this.service.check()
.map(value => {
  if (value) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
  }
}
```

and then do the `subscribe()` where you call this code

Comment: I already have the .map implemented the problem is it's getting the else condition executed before the check() function finshe's execution. So it's always going to the else condition

Comment: because the code needs to be within a `map(...)`, `subscribe(...)` or any other observable operator.

Comment: inside an `async` function one may `await` for a Promise to resolve though (these days)