# Angular: Return result of subscribe

Tags: angular, api, exception

I am getting an error on IProject
`must return a value`.

I want to return the result from the api.

```
public getProjectDetails(projectId: number): IProject {
        this.testStationService.getProjectById(projectId)
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    return res;
                });
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912629/4125622

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your service method as well

`return this.testStationService.getProjectById(projectId)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a value of an asynchronous Observable, synchronously. So by the time `getProjectById` emits a value, the function `getProjectDetails` has already finished and return nothing.

You have to return the Observable itself and subscribe to it where you need its values, or even better use the async-pipe -> https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

So `getProjectDetails` would look like this:

```
public getProjectDetails(projectId: number): Observable<IProject> {
    return this.testStationService.getProjectById(projectId);
}
```